# Left right DTO to object AutoMapper- C#

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

We recently implemented automapper and currently looking to optimise assigning values from the DTO to model. currently we are doing something like

```
model.Property1 = dto.Property1;
model.SomePropertyType = dto.PropertyType;
model.Property2 = dto.Property2;
```

Now this could go pretty long and repetitive task to all Mapper classes. 
Is there a way to simplify this on AutoMapper?

Comment: I dont understand, automapper is made for you  to remove the simple binding like model.Property1 = dto.Property1; and
model.Property2 = dto.Property2; . You just need to register your mapping ( CreateMap<domain,dtor>();) (use profile) and then use the mapper interface _mapper.Map<Domain>(x)...simple binding (same type, same name) are taken care of by automapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Automapper` then have you not defined the maps (profile)? I believe, you might have defined those so please use those to instruct `Automapper` how to map source object to Target.

Another point `Automapper` also works based on naming convention, so if you have same property name in both source and target then it will automap automatically. So you don't unnecessary define the mapping fort it. To override mapping for a property (or whose name/type does not match), you can use `.ForMember` method.

```
cfg.CreateMap<MyDTO, MyModel>()

                .ForMember(destination => destination.PropertyType,

               opts => opts.MapFrom(source => source.SomePropertyType ));
```

You can read about `Automapper` at [here](http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html).

Now in the code to get the mapped object, use it like

```
Mapper.Map<MyModel>(object of MyDTO);
```

Comment: how about if there are multiple Names that does not match?

Comment: If name does not match then you need to define the mapping using `ForMember` if targeted object property need to be populated. If the source has property which should not be mapped to target (if name is same) then use `Ignore` method in `ForMember` and if the target property does not exist then don't do any thing.